# Select .pro file in yocto recipe

Tags: qt, yocto

My project has 2 .pro files and when I'm building my project with yocto for my target device, it is trying to embed every files of the project whereas some of them don't need to be embeedded on the target device. I have this error message: "Files were installed but not shipped in any package. Please set FILES such that these items are packaged. Alternatively if they are unneeded, avoid installing them, or delete them within do_install."

If anyone could tell me how to avoid yocto from trying to embed every file and maybe also how to tell him which .pro to read, that would be amazing.

Comment: Can you show your recipe?

Comment: I canno't show it since it is for professional use and I know that it is not convenient for you to help without seeing it but feel free to ask me whatever you want about it and I will try my best to be as precise as possible

Comment: How are you specifying the source files?

Comment: Just solved the problem by using the QMAKE_PROFILES flag in my recipe to target a specific pro file. Thanks for your quick answers !